# Liveweb Plugin for Powerpoint: Support for HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, powerpoint

I'm thinking of using the Liveweb plugin for Powerpoint, to embed a web page in a Powerpoint presentation.

Does Liveweb support HTML5 Canvas? Does it support Javascript?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 1):

Shyam Pillai's LiveWeb?  It simply embeds an instance of the browser control into your presentation.  It doesn't support any web technologies ... just turns the browser loose on them, so it'll depend on the MSIE version in place and what it supports and your Internet settings (ie, whether javascript is disabled or not).

Or the short version:  Can't answer that.  Try it for yourself and see.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So far it doesn't seem to be working.  I can access a web page from inside a PowerPoint slide show. I can use the navigation on the page and navigate around the site. But when I go to a page that uses HTML5 Canvas, the Canvas objects don't yet appear.