# Shyam Pillai's LiveWeb WebGL support

Tags: html, webgl, powerpoint

I've installed [LiveWeb](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm#.VCFu8rmnaLX) and I tried adding a web page (having WebGL canvas) to the Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007. it's not working , Does LiveWeb has the support for WebGL canvas?.
My IE supports WebGL.

Note: I've posted a new question since I can't add a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455981/liveweb-plugin-for-powerpoint-support-for-html5-canvas)

Regards,

RajanM

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have answered your own question.

Microsoft PowerPoint 2007 is a product from 2007. Microsoft did not support WebGL until IE11 which is 2013 which is 6 years later.

Comment: Since LiveWeb hosts a browser control that handles the HTML, I doubt it matters at all what version of PPT you have; it's more a matter of the browser (or perhaps whether the browser control behaves the same as the full browser).  In any case, it'd be best to contact Shyam about this.  I'm pretty sure there's a contact link on his site.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've sent a mail to Shyam. I'll post the info once I got the reply from him.

Comment: I've not got any replies from Shyam , so unable to comment further.